# Why am I getting "The magic number in GZip header is not correct." error using OWIN auth against Azure SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, connection-string, owin

Nothing on Google or SO relates to this specific problem, so asking a new question. I created a brand new Asp.Net MVC *Web Application* with the standard *user-security* option. I also created an empty database in Azure.

I did nothing but change the default connection string to this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="data source=mydatabase.database.windows.net;initial catalog=Feedback;persist security info=True;user id=LeaveFeedbackuser;password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and the default connection factory to this:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

On attempting to register (when I would expect it to normally create the `AspNetUsers` and related tables) I get the following error:

> The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are
>   passing in a GZip stream.    Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.InvalidDataException: The magic number
>   in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip
>   stream.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 153:            { Line 154:                var user = new
>   ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email }; Line
>   155:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user,
>   model.Password); Line 156:                if (result.Succeeded) Line
>   157:                {

What has any of this to do with GZip and what is causing this error? This has stopped me getting OWIN working with my Azure database for several days now.

Comment: Ok so for the sake of clarity: 1.  the Db is on Azure but the Web App is where local or Azure? 2. You wont be using OWIN to connect your web app to the Db but rather you're trying to use AspIdentity, which is OWIN middleware for the membership system of your application. 3. Can you simply run a CREATE table against the db, completely independent of AspIdentity using standard ADO.NET and your connection string, say in the Home/Index action. i.e. ascertain whether this has anything to do AspIdentity at all instead of just Azure setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my "theory". I think the Sql Azure Db is not setup correctly or the connection string is in error.

We know that when AspIdentity attempts to hit the database on Login and finds the tables are not set up it will try to create them.

I think there is a breakdown/bug in the AspIdentity code that under this circumstance swallows the exception generated from the bad connection string and thus the failed setup and continues on it's merry way trying to provide an authentication ticket to the client.

If we look into the code for [Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer.TicketSerializer](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security/DataHandler/Serializer/TicketSerializer.cs) we find some GZip action:

```
 public virtual byte[] Serialize(AuthenticationTicket model)
        {
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var compression = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
                {
                    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(compression))
                    {
                        Write(writer, model);
                    }
                }
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

So basically I think AspIdentity fails on the connection, this error is swallowed, the Owin pipeline continues processing the request but when it hits the `TicketSerializer`  perhaps a null value or some other bogus value is passed in which Gzip tries to zip and Boom!

Weirdo YSOD output ensues.

> The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are
>   passing in a GZip stream. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.

AspIdentity is not properly short circuiting OWIN request processing for this particular event.

Probably utter nonsense but I'll throw it out there anyway.

Comment: Those clues allowed me to try a number of different options and I now have it working. I still do not understand completely why it went wrong, but it does appear to be related to the database login. Thanks for all your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 9):

I experienced a similar problem.

The Entity Framework `__MigrationHistory` `Model` column contains GZipped data. If the data in this column is corrupted then your app won't be able to unzip the data and you'll get the error.

In my case, the corruption occurred by trying to manually insert into this able.

My solution: delete corrupted `__MigrationHistory` rows and related DB changes and allow the app to migrate the database properly.

Comment: is there any way to trace which row in migration table is corrupted?

Comment: @malik perhaps try to update by a single migration at a time and see which one you get to.

Comment: I am now facing the same issue when pushing new changes to production. However, I always manually insert the SQL scripts whereas locally I use Code-First Migrations. Any suggestions?

Comment: how did you find which rows were corrupted